# 5D Kalman filter is not working, and we're not sure where we're going wrong

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, kalman-filter

Right now we're attempting to create a 5 Dimensional Kalman filter that recieves as input the x and y coordinates of a small bug that is wandering around in the box. We observe this bug as it makes roughly 2000 movements, then predict it's position from then forward. The dimensions are x-coord, y-coord, velocity, heading, and angular acceleration. Following is the code that we have so far.

```
#x is a list of five variables - x, y, velocity, angularVelocity, angularAcceleration
#currentmeasurement is the x and y that were observed
def kalman_filter(x, P, currentmeasurement, lastMeasurement = None):
        prevmeasurement = []

    #if there is a lastMeasurement argument, it becomes measurement
    if lastMeasurement:
        prevmeasurement = [lastMeasurement[0], lastMeasurement[1], x.value[3][0]]

    #if there is no lastMeasurement argument, the current measurement becomes measurement.
    else:
        prevmeasurement = [x.value[0][0], x.value[1][0], x.value[3][0]]

    #Prediction Step
    a = x.value[3][0]
    F = matrix([
        [1., 0., cos(a), 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., sin(a), 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., dt],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])

    x = (F * x) + u
    P = F * P * F.transpose()

    #we can calculate the heading from our observations.
    heading = atan2(currentmeasurement[0][1] - prevmeasurement[1], currentmeasurement[0][0] - prevmeasurement[0])
    while(abs(heading - prevmeasurement[2]) > pi):
        heading = heading + 2*pi*((prevmeasurement[2]-heading)/abs(prevmeasurement[2]-heading))

    #perhaps the velocity should also be calculated? 

    # measurement update
    dt = 1.
    u = matrix([[0.], [0.], [0.], [0.], [0.]])      # external motion
    H =  matrix([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],              #the measurement function
             [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
             [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])

    R =  matrix([[1., 0., .0],                      #measurement uncertainty
             [0., 1., .0],
             [0., 0., 1.]])
    I =  matrix([[]])                               #a 5x5 identity matrix
    I.identity(5)


    prevmeasurement = [currentmeasurement[0][0], currentmeasurement[0][1], heading]
    Z = matrix([prevmeasurement])
    y = Z.transpose() - (H * x)
    S = H * P * H.transpose() + R
    K = P * H.transpose() * S.inverse()
    x = x + (K * y)
    P = (I - (K * H)) * P

    return x,P
```

This is resulting in wildly incorrect estimations. We're not sure what we're doing wrong here - I think we're following all of the steps correctly, but not sure if we have all of the required matrices correct. Any input would be helpful!

Comment: Reduce the data set to a few points, where four of the parameters are fixed values, and the fifth follows a well defined progression, e.g. x = 1,2,3,4,5 with y=0, v=1, heading=+x-direction, angular=0. Then run the algorithm and see what you get.

Comment: In addition to the structural issues I pointed out in my answer, you should consider whether you think your frictionless, constant velocity, constant angular velocity bug model really reflects reality.  Your update step is ideal for something like a puck on an air-hockey table.

Answer (score 1):

The top comment has the wrong description.  Your state must be `x, y, velocity, angle, angularVelocity`

You're missing `Q`, the process covariance.  It should reflect how much your state can change between updates, and is added to your update of `P` in the predict step.

You're building an EKF (since your update requires trig, it is nonlinear).  You've constructed a matrix `F` which performs your state update, but what you need for the process covariance update is the *Jacobian* of your update function.  In your case it looks like:

```
J = matrix([
    [1., 0., cos(a), -sin(a), 0.],
    [0., 1., sin(a), cos(a), 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 1., dt],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

If your only direct measurement is position, you should not compute heading and use it as a measurement.  Let the KF do it.

You should set `R` to be the real uncertainties of the measurement.  The noise represented by `Q`, `R`, and propagated in `P` is more important than your state `x` if you want the KF to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a very similar problem, and having exactly the same issues.  Given noisy *(x,y)* measurements of a robot's position, and the knowledge that it is turning at constant velocity in a circle of constant radius, predict its next position.

I also attempted a 5D EKF, which would blow up after a few iterations.  My state consisted of:

`[x, y, distance_per_timestep, heading, heading_delta_per_timestep]`

I tried numerous formulations for the state transition matrix (Jacobian of ***f**(x)*, modified version of Jacobian, etc).  In increasing desperation, I tried manually tweaking Kalman gains, covariances, everything... nothing seemed to work.

My final solution, which works amazingly well, was to use 2D Kalman filter on *x* and *y* positions, with velocity, heading, and turning rate calculated from the previous 3 positions and used as control inputs to the state estimation update.  I tried other variations on that theme (state of `[x, y, vx, vy, ax, ay]` and so forth, but nothing beat the KISS (keep it simple, stupid) approach.

At first I used the raw, noisy measurements to calculate velocity, heading, and delta_heading.  I tried using my state estimates of *x* and *y* after the filter had run for a while, but that led to instability too- very slow onset, but a gently growing weave back and forth across the ground truth track that eventually turned into a piece of Spirograph art!  I later found that if i did my measurement update first, then used *those* state values (after measurement, but before state update), I'd get slightly better performance than the raw measurements.

I'm not sure if my approach would solve your problem (I keep getting noisy measurements, and only need to predict a few moves ahead in order to "catch" my runaway), but take from it what you may.

I am also very interested in knowing **why** my EKF blew up, and also how to formulate the correct **F** matrix in a non-linear problem like this- the "proper" Jacobian, if I calculated it correctly, causes the EKF to blow up almost immediately!

I'd be very interested in hearing your solution, or any other advances you may have made!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Q the model noise matrix
2. Your H matrix should be the Jacobian. Not your Q matrix.

   3. Don't estimate anything for the filter. Let the Kalman do it for you and you stick to the observed space
      If you send the main script I can help more.